# Ajax response string as function name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can call javascript funtion if i have string which is same as function name?

I have Ajax request and response:

```
{"message":"Updated","function":"UpdateClientsData()"}

Submit.done(function (response){                
    var resultArray = JSON.parse(response);

    $.each( resultArray, function( key, value ) {       

        if( key == "function")
        {
            var run = value;
            [run]();                        
        }                   
    });

function UpdateClientsData()
{
    console.log("aaaaa");
}
```

I get error message saying 'Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function'. What I am missing here?

Error Line `[run]();`

Thank you

Comment: Which line is the error message on?

Comment: Where has `Submit` been defined?

Comment: its just a snipet of the code everything works

Comment: Are you able to find the line of the error in the console?

Comment: error is on [run](); line

Comment: Could you do `console.log(run)` just before that line.

Comment: Output: UpdateClientsData()

Comment: This is really not very good practice, and should be avoided. Use an object literal and keys instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1tqvxehq/

Comment: Use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), like `eval(value+'()')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use bracket notation without specifying an object. Using `[run]` will be interpreted as an array literal.

Use the `window` object to access the function:

```
window[run]();
```

But first you need to remove the `()` to get only the function name:

```
var run = value.replace('()', '');
```